# select2 closeOnSelect:false not working with ajax

Tags: jquery-select2

I am starting to work with select2, and am liking it more and more the more i play with it.  I'm trying to leverage the remote data population of a multiselect, but everytime i choose an option, it just closes the dropdown and i have to type and search again.  I can see this becoming very annoying very quickly.

```
$('#test').select2({
    multiple:true,
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    closeOnSelect:false,
    placeholder: 'Search',
    ajax: {
        url: "http://www.weighttraining.com/sm/search",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function(term, page) {
            return {
                types: ["exercise"],
                limit: -1,
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function(data, page ) {
            return { results: data.results.exercise }
        }
    },
    formatResult: function(exercise) { 
        return "<div class='select2-user-result'>" + exercise.term + "</div>"; 
    },
    formatSelection: function(exercise) { 
        return exercise.term; 
    },
    initSelection : function (element, callback) {
        var elementText = $(element).attr('data-init-text');
        callback({"term":elementText});
    }
});
```

i forked this and made a few changes to it:

http://jsfiddle.net/z64erawf/1/

What am i missing? Thanks!

Comment: it seems to be working fine for me in your fiddle, im not seeing what you are describing...are you talking about using arrow keys?

Comment: If i type "ab" in the select box, i get results in the dropdown.  But when i choose one, the select box goes away.  Then i have to type "ab" again and select2 fires off another search.  I was thinking that closeOnSelect:false would have kept the dropdown open so i could select 3 different options rather than doing the search 3 times.

Comment: Ok, yea this is a documented bug , see here https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/2264